# image format for Screenshot

Tags: screenshot

In 12.04, can the image format for Screenshot be jpeg? I change the file name to save to to be ended with ".jpg", but Gnome image viewer seems not be able to open it saying

> Error interpreting JPEG image file (Not a JPEG file: starts with 0x89
>   0x50)

One example image is here http://dl.dropbox.com/u/13029929/c1p18.jpg
Is it a true jpeg image file?

Thanks!

Comment: I get the feeling that `.png` is the only possibility, even in `xfce4-screenshooter` and `scrot`.

Comment: How can I know if a image file is jpg or png?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The file you are linking at is a PNG image, true. I understood it via the `file` command.

There doesn't seem to be an option at the default `gnome-screenshot` tool for saving as JPEG format, but there is at Shutter, which can be easily installed via the Ubuntu Software Center:

[image]